# Time for some proverbs!

Tags: visual, rebus, english

Can you find these proverbs?

1.

[image]

  2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

5.

[image]

6.

[image]

7.

[image]

8.

[image]

9.

[image]

10.

[image]

Comment: English tag please...

Comment: Done!!! I didn't know about that tag. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give these proverbs again in text and emojis? Now I can't access Imgur at all. Try Registering on Tinypic.com so I can access it.

Comment: @Ak19 Tinypic has gone, use Cubeupload.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Yeah, sure! Probably in the next one. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Full solution, thanks to @JonMarkPerry and @jafe

1)

> "Better late than never"
> [image]

2)

> "Don't bite the hand that feeds you"
> [image]

3)

> "Easy come easy go"
> [image]

4)

> "Hope for the best and prepare for the worst"
> [image]

5)

> "Knowledge is power"
> [image]

6)

> "Fortune favors the brave"
> [image]

7)

> "Like father like son"
> [image]

8)

> "Action speaks louder than words"
> [image]

9)

> "A picture equals 1000 words"
> [image]

10)

> "Fall seven times, stand up eight"
> [image]

Comment: @Ak19 is that good enough?

Comment: I would appreciate a small explanation after each of these. They are not obvious to me.

Comment: is this better? @KateGregory

Comment: The first picture is a fortune cookie, on the paper is a 'fortune'. The lion is brave. The middle picture I think is either a homophone of 'flavours' (try it in a Chinese accent!), or favors as in treats. Anyway, the first and last make it clear.

Comment: for the first one, why does that mean never? for 6, why is that brave?

Comment: @KateGregory sign language for never, the lion is the logo of a company called brave

Answer (score 4):

1.

> Better late than never

3.

> Easy come, easy go

5.

> Knowledge is Power

6.

> Fortune favors the brave

9.

> A picture equals 1000 words

The remaining answers are given in the other answers.

Comment: Sorry, I saw your update just now.

Comment: sorry but how does 6 work? thanks

Comment: Fortune cookies, wedding favors, Brave software @omegakrypton

Answer (score 3):

10.

> Fall seven times, stand up eight